# Writing a maven plugin that reads annotations from source files

Tags: java, maven, annotations

My idea is to write a maven plugin that generates code (just simple json) based on some annotations in my Java code. The annotated classes may be part of a used library or in my own code.

What I want is a plugin that gets a fixed set of class names (by configuration in pom). It walks through these classes, searches it for annotations on properties and generates code based on the gathered information.

- Is that possible?
- How can I achieve this?
- Is there an existing plugin that does something like that?

Comment: You probably want an *annotation processor* instead of a Maven plugin.

Comment: With an annotation processor you cannot process already compiled code. Right?